# Bump Charts in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, visualization

I have an idea of creating a bump chart for showing mean differences between groups.

Normally bump charts use years as X axis. Insted I have two different cities for same year. I just want to plot top 10 values for each city and show priority using bump charts.

I have already created the bump chart. Next, I want to add the labels but they all sit on just one x value and y value, i think it is because of the the filter creating just one column.

[image: Plot]

I can't use reprex because this data is corporate and can't share. However here's the code, perhaps you could fix this issue.

```
base_carreras %>% arrange(-Promedio_region_egresados) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=sur_miembro,y=Promedio_region_egresados,
             group=FamiliasProfesionales)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(data = base_carreras %>% filter(sur_miembro == 'Resto del país'),
            aes(label = FamiliasProfesionales), size = 5, hjust = 1) +
    geom_text(data = base_carreras %>% filter(sur_miembro == 'Sur'),
            aes(label = FamiliasProfesionales), size = 5, hjust = 1) +
  ggbump::geom_bump()
```

There may be better charts or alternatives for plotting this. Please I need your help.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some **fake data**. We don't need your corporate  data. But the issue is most likely a typo. From the image I would guess it should be `filter(sur_miembro == 'Resto del **P**aís')`